# I've got a account in Superuser but I forgot email? Can I possible get it back?

Tags: support, email

So, I've registered and used a account in Superuser 2 years ago. It's quite inactive account but I don't want to register new one from beginning. Here's it:

> https://superuser.com/users/98110/user98110

Can I get it back? And how?

Can I possible by any chance ask for this user (me) registered email address? Because I tried about 10 email addresses that I used 5 years ago until now, but not single one works. I just want to know the email in order to login it and reset password.

What's the worst thing I can do with another stranger email (if anyone assume) in this case? So believe me and help me a way to get back my user account.

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @Sathya I'm afraid that won't work if the user doesn't have access to their old account to begin with.

Comment: Surely, it doesn't allow. Because merge a account that you unable to login is the same case that you claim another person is you, and try to take his/her account by merge them into yours.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I get it back? And how?

Usually you'd go to the [forgotten password page](https://meta.superuser.com/users/account-recovery). If you tried all e-mail addresses and still can't log in, please [contact the Stack Exchange team](https://meta.superuser.com/contact) directly.

> Can I possible by any chance ask for this user (me) registered email address?

For privacy reasons we cannot hand out this information, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. At the moment, I already got it back. It's one of my inactive Gmail address which I still have access authority. I've no idea how I miss this email for the 1st place, I remember that I also tried it in pass-recovery procedural.